# Continuity of an operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Working in the $\textit{Hilbert space}$ of sequences
$$
X=\ell^2=\Big\{\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2<\infty, x_n\in\mathbb{R}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\Big\},
$$ with the dot product $\langle x,y\rangle =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n y_n$, I have to prove that the operator $$T:\overline{B_X}(0,1)\to\overline{B_X}(0,1)$$ defined as $$T(x)=(\sqrt{1-||x||^2},x_1,x_2,x_3,...), \quad x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$$
is continuous. Since it is non-linear I have tried to prove it with the classic definition of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. I got this:
$$||T(x)-T(y)||=\sqrt{2-||x||^2-||y||^2-2\sqrt{1-||x||^2-||y||^2+||x||^2||y||^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n-y_n|^2}.$$
Any hint?

Comment: Much easier to use sequential  definition of continuity.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by 'and which is exactly its image of $\overline{B_X}(0,1)$'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the function $\gamma(t)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. You have
$$
\|Tx-Ty\|^2=|\gamma(\|x\|)-\gamma(\|y\|)|^2+\|x-y\|^2.
$$
Fix $\varepsilon>0$. As $\gamma$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that $|\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)|<{\varepsilon/{\sqrt2}}$ if $|t-s|<\delta'$. Put $\delta=\min\{\delta',{\varepsilon}\}$. Then, if $\|x-y\|<\delta$,
$$
|\,\|x\|-\|y\|\,|\leq\|x-y\|<\delta\leq\delta', 
$$
and so
$$
\|Tx-Ty\|^2=|\gamma(\|x\|)-\gamma(\|y\|)|^2+\|x-y\|^2\leq\frac{\varepsilon^2}2+\frac{\varepsilon^2}2=\varepsilon^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\|x\|$ is continuous. Therefore $g(x)=(\sqrt {1-\|x\|^2},0,0,0,...)$ is continuous on $\overline {B_X}(0,1)$. Now $h(x)=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$ is also continuous. Therefore $T(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ is continuous on $\overline {B_X}(0,1)$.

Comment: I think that in infinite dimension you can't claim that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous because each component is continuous, so you have to prove it somehow.

Comment: @KingSlayer . $h$ is continuous because it is an isometry. $j(y)=\sqrt {1-y^2}$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1].$ Now $k(z)=(z,0,0,0,...)$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ into $X$ because it is an isometry. And $h(x)=k(j(f(x))).$